# Adding Swagger leading Publish failure Asp.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, publish

Getting error:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file.

But `startup.cs` here is fully loaded:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WeatherForecast API", Version = "v1" });
    });

}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "WeatherForecast API V1");
    });
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the application and then republish the application. Besides, in my asp.net 5 application, I use the default SwaggerEndPoint as below: `app.UseSwagger();   app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "APIApp v1"));`, then publish the application to IIS, everything works well, so you can try to use this SwaggerEndpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. There is the same issue on GitHub and it looks like the problem is your project path.

Check out this comment.
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/20330#issuecomment-722461550

Comment: still issue is same

Comment: @MURALIDHARDUBEY Can you share your code in GitHub or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I had project on D:/ex1/ex2/ex3/code and when moving it to Downloads it worked.

Have you tried the same?

[Edit]

I think clearing my %temp% folder resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this build output:

```
Starting to update your API
Generating swagger file to 'C:\Users\(...hidden...)\bin\Release\net7.0\swagger.json'.
Failed to generate swagger file. Error dotnet swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output "C:\Users\(...hidden...)\bin\Release\net7.0\swagger.json" "C:\Users\(...hidden...)\bin\Release\net7.0\Sly_Backend.dll" v1

Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Password')
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.CheckArgumentNull(Object value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue(String keyword, String value)
```

Reason: I have the db connection string password in the User Secrets

I temporarily **added the password** directly to the **program.cs**

```
//conStrBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["DbPasswort"];
conStrBuilder.Password = "(hidden password)";
```

With that, build and deploy was working.