# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I find it incredible that this is problematic given MS attention to Azure but I must bring up an old problem as why has MS not solved this.

After running into Swagger problems with my Web API app, I found this tutorial and followed it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0

One can not get much simpler and my `program.cs` looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And I then follow the "Publish the API" steps and hit the publish button, but get this:

> failed to generate swagger file. Error dotnet swagger tofile
> --serializeasv2 --output "C:\Users\jmcfe\source\repos\azure1\azure1\bin\Release\net6.0\swagger.json"
> "C:\Users\jmcfe\source\repos\azure1\azure1\bin\Release\net6.0\azure1.dll"
> v1

Now some suggest moving my project to Downloads but why is this still an issue

Comment: If you run that command line directly do you get any more helpful errors? `dotnet swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output "C:\Users\jmcfe\source\repos\azure1\azure1\bin\Release\net6.0\swagger.json" "C:\Users\jmcfe\source\repos\azure1\azure1\bin\Release\net6.0\azure1.dll`

Comment: Shouldn't you use swagger in development enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

***I followed the same steps to create and deploy web API to Azure Web App Service.***

- Created default .NET core 6.0 WEB API in visual studio:

**Local Output:**

[image]

- Created a **new web app**, **app service plan**. Created new **API service**, configured everything and created new publish profile.

[image: -]

- Tried to publish this profile to App Service and I was getting the same error as you mentioned:

[image]

- This error is occurring due to API configuration.
- To resolve this I cleared ***temp folder***, deleted ***bin, .config, obj*** folders. Performed ***Clean and Rebuild*** operation.
- Followed the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74093408/19991670) answer given by @*Harshitha* and modified the `Program.cs` code as shown below:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

- Created new publish profile and deployed again.

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

***You can skip API management configuration while creating the publish profile to deploy the WEB API to Azure App Service.***

[image]

You can configure API management in portal after deploying the application to Azure.

**References:**
Few references regarding the same issue:

1. [.net - Adding Swagger leading Publish failure Asp.NET Core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731087/adding-swagger-leading-publish-failure-asp-net-core)
2. [api - Getting error when publishing webAPI to Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295741/getting-error-when-publishing-webapi-to-azure)

Comment: that solved the problem, not sure why MS does not update Azure docs